# How do I correctly deploy a .war file?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, deployment

I am attempting to deploy a `test.war` file for the first time.

I have installed `Tomcat 7` using `apt-get` on `Ubuntu server 12.04`.

The webapps directory is located here: `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`.

Tomcat 7 is installed here: `/usr/share/tomcat7`.

I have produced a basic web project called `test` using `Eclipse` which works fine using a local Tomcat 7 server. In the project I have a basic index.jsp file and a Testservlet.java `servlet` file.

Using an FTP client I have uploaded the test.war file to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` where it automatically deploys. But how do I browse to this directory in a web browser to view the website?

I have previously attempted to move the project inside the `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT` directory which allows me to view the index.jsp file when i navigate to `http://my-host.com:8080/test` but I get a 404 error when I attempt to browse to the Testservlet page at this address `http://my-host.com:8080/Testservlet`.

This is the Testservlet annotation:

`@WebServlet(description = "a test servlet", urlPatterns = { "/Testservlet" })`

So what am I missing in this whole process? Is there something else I need to do after deploying the .war file in the webapps directory to be able to browse to the website without having to put it in to the `/ROOT` sub directory?

EDIT:

I get a 404 error when I navigate to http://my-host.com:8080/test/Testservlet AND when I navigate to http://my-host.com:8080/test when the test.war is deployed in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`.

EDIT:

This is the web.xml for test project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

EDIT: removed annotation in servlet and adding servlet mapping to web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet> 
                <servlet-name>test</servlet-name> 
                <servlet-class>testpackage.Testservlet</servlet-class> 
        </servlet> 
        <servlet-mapping> 
                <servlet-name>test</servlet-name> 
                <url-pattern>/Testservlet</url-pattern> 
        </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

EDIT: added Testservlet.java code:

```
package testpackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Testservlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out.println("This is a test servlet");
    }

}
```

EDIT: error logs

```
 - - [26/May/2014:15:19:35 +0100] "GET /Testservlet HTTP/1.1" 404 988
 - - [26/May/2014:15:19:35 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 988
 - - [26/May/2014:15:43:50 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 955
 - - [26/May/2014:15:51:36 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 955
 - - [26/May/2014:15:51:40 +0100] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 967
 - - [26/May/2014:16:13:12 +0100] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 967
 - - [26/May/2014:16:13:20 +0100] "GET /root/test HTTP/1.1" 404 982
 - - [26/May/2014:16:16:19 +0100] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 967
 - - [26/May/2014:16:16:58 +0100] "GET /test/Testservlet HTTP/1.1" 404 1003
 - - [26/May/2014:16:32:09 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 955
 - - [26/May/2014:16:35:38 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 955
 - - [26/May/2014:16:40:16 +0100] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 967
```

Comment: You should put your *.war to /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps and rename it to ROOT.war. Or you can just put test.war in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps then you should be able to access your servlet via http://my-host.com:8080/test/Testservlet

Comment: I get a 404 error when I navigate to `http://my-host.com:8080/test/Testservlet` AND when I navigate to `http://my-host.com:8080/test`.

Comment: What is the directory your test.war in?

Comment: If I move the test directory into `webapps/ROOT/` I CAN browse to index.jsp with `http://my-host.com:8080/test` but not `http://my-host.com:8080/test/Testservlet` where i get a 404.

Comment: the test.war is in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/`.

Comment: add your web.xml,please

Comment: I added it to the bottom of question.

Comment: Seems that annotations isn't working. Have you tried to manually map your servlet in web.xml?

Comment: Yes I have I attempted removing the annotation in the servlet and added the servlet xml code, which I have put at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I get the same 404 errors with the test.war deployed in webapps...

Comment: What is your TestServlet code is. Do you get any exceptions in tomcat logs?

Comment: Added the testservlet code. It runs fine on my localhost on my machine via eclipse.

Comment: also added tomcat7 logs

Comment: Do you see test dir in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/?

Comment: Yes I do see it there.

Comment: @user979349 I decided to completely uninstall tomcat7 and installed it manually and it now works. So we can assume it was configured wrongly through apt-get. Thanks for you help!